# Initialize array on the heap without specifying its length

Tags: c++, arrays

I was reading Bjarne Stroustrup's *Programming Principles and Practice Using C++* (second edition). On page 597:

```cpp
double* p5 = new double[] {0,1,2,3,4};
```

> ...; the number of elements can be left out when a set of elements is provided.

I typed the code above into Visual Studio 2022, and I get red underlines saying that "incomplete type is not allowed" (same thing happens when I define `p5` as a data member), nevertheless, **the code compiles and runs successfully**.

[image]
[image]

May I ask if it is fine to define array in such way? If so, why would Visual Studio show those red underlines...?

Comment: *and I get red underlines saying...* -- Those "red underlines" do not determine if the actual code is valid.  Does the code compile and run?  Actual compiler errors have coded numbers, starting with the letter `C` like `C1234`.  Anything else is from the Intellisense feature of the IDE.  Intellisense is *not* a C++ compiler -- it makes mistakes, even though most of the time, it "works".  Many programmers who know what they're doing just ignore the "red underlines" and are only concerned with whether the program compiles successfully or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May I ask if it is fine to define array in such way?

Yes, starting from **C++11** it is valid. From [new expression's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new):

> ```
> double* p = new double[]{1,2,3}; // creates an array of type double[3]
> ```

---

This means in your example:

```
double* p5 = new double[] {0,1,2,3,4};
```

creates an array of type `double[5]`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v6zz1hP66)

---

##### Note

This was proposed in [p1009r2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1009r2.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, so I think this may be a Visual Studio's bug?

Comment: @CPPL Yes, starting from C++11 the code is valid. See i have added a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v6zz1hP66) link in my answer which shows that it works in gcc, msvc and clang.

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be on the heap then use

```
std::vector<double> v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

if it can be on the stack then use

```
std::array a{0., 1., 2., 3., 4.}; // all elements must have the right type
std::array b(std::to_array<double>({1, 2, 3})); // when conversion is easier than typing fully typed objects
```

Comment: True, but doesn't answer the question.